# Is polynomial reduction reversible?

Tags: complexity-theory, theory

Is this statement true or false : "*If a problem A is polynomially reducible to a problem B, then problem B must also be polynomially reducible to A*".

Comment: Did I answer your question? If so please accept if not please put a comment.

Answer (score 3):

**This is wrong**, consider the **reducible to** relationship as **its hardness is less than or equal**. For example, if A is polynomially reducible to B, it means that A <= B in terms of hardness (amount of computation needed to solve it). If A is reducible to B it means that A is simpler than (or as hard as) B, which means if you can solve B you can solve A, as well.

Some supplementary information:
Any problem in P, which are problems that are simple and can be solved in polynomial time, is reducible to any problem in NP-complete (e.g. SAT). This means that problems in P are simpler than problems in NP-complete. Now, if your statement was true then problems in NP-complete would have been solved in polynomial time, which is seemingly impossible (no one has proved or disproved it). And if anybody solves it there will be chaos!!!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem

[SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem)

[A world with P=NP](https://www.quora.com/If-I-just-proved-that-P-NP-how-do-I-start-taking-over-the-world)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (slightly edited) illustration from a very well-known graduate text on Complexity Theory (C.H. Papadimitriou, Computational Complexity). It shows what a reduction from *A* to *B* is.

[image: Reduction from A to B]

A reduction from *A* to *B* is an algorithm for solving *A* that is composed of a translation *R* that maps every instance of *A* into an instance of *B*, and an algorithm for *B*. The translation must ensure that the answer for *A*(*x*) and for *B*(*R*(*x*)) is the same.

The existence of a such a translation does not guarantee that the inverse translation also exists. Intuitively the images of instances of *A* might form a subset of *easy* instances of *B*.

Anyone can easily suggest simple examples of problems where reduction in one direction does not guarantee a reduction in the other direction. For instance, 2-SAT is trivially reducible to SAT, yet 2-SAT is solvable in polynomial time, while SAT is NP-complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Consider the following problem:

> Given a finite automaton, does it halt on a given input?

The answer to this problem happens always to be yes since all deterministic finite automata halt on all inputs. However, this problem is polynomial-time reducible to the following problem:

> Given a Turing machine, does it halt on a given input?

The answer to this problem happens to be undecidable in the general case. This is the halting problem. However, if we had an oracle for this problem, we could certainly use it to answer the first question, albeit much less efficiently:

1. Produce a Turing machine equivalent to the DFA
2. Use the oracle to determine whether the Turing machine halts.

The halting problem for Turing machines, however, is not polynomial-time reducible to the halting problem for DFAs.